# How can I parse multiple URLs in feedparser (Python)?

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm making a little webapp with some fixed feeds (fixed as in, you can't add feeds like in Feedly or Google Reader)

I tried this, with no luck

```
RSS_URLS = [
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/RockPaperShotgun',
    'http://www.gameinformer.com/b/MainFeed.aspx?Tags=preview',
    ]

feed = feedparser.parse(RSS_URLS)

for post in feed.entries:
    print post.title
```

And this, with no luck

```
RSS_URLS = [
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/RockPaperShotgun',
    'http://www.gameinformer.com/b/MainFeed.aspx?Tags=preview',
    ]

feed = []
for url in RSS_URLS:
    feed.append(feedparser.parse(url))

for post in feed.entries:
    print post.title
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second approach is OK, but as you append the feeds into a list, 
you also will get a list of feeds of entries, thus:

```
RSS_URLS = [
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/RockPaperShotgun',
    'http://www.gameinformer.com/b/MainFeed.aspx?Tags=preview',
    ]

feeds = []
for url in RSS_URLS:
    feeds.append(feedparser.parse(url))

for feed in feeds:
    for post in feed.entries:
        print post.title
```

or to make a flat list of all posts, `extend` the list with the list of new entries from each url:

```
posts = []
for url in RSS_URLS:
    posts.extend(feedparser.parse(url).entries)

for post in posts:
    print post.title
```